# Bigquery backend error during table export

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm not able to export either of my table on Bigquery to GCS as a csv file.

```
Errors:
Backend error. Job aborted.

Recent Job ID: red-road-574:job_toeIKGmQhfTngclTNjy0z-Gt3_k
Start Time: 11:51am, 30 Jul 2014
End Time: 11:52am, 30 Jul 2014
Source Table: red-road-574:Geotab_test.LatLong
Destination URI: gs://GeotabBigData/red-road-574-temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the bucket name is the problem here, as buckets are lowercase only per the [GCS bucket naming guidelines](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/bucketnaming)

Comment: "GeotabBigData" is my project name here. I created a bucket named "red-road-574-temp" under this project. If I used gs://red-road-574-temp, it'll tell me it's an invalid bucket, and no job will be created at all

Comment: If the bucket is red-road-574-temp, then use gs://red-road-574-temp/my-results.csv (you also need to supply a destination file/object name)