# BigQuery "Backend Error, Job aborted" when exporting data

Tags: google-bigquery

The export job for one of my tables fails in BigQuery with no error message, I checked the job id hoping to get more info but it just says "Backend Error, Job aborted". I used the command-line tool with tis command

```
bq extract --project_id=my-proj-id --destination_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON 'test.table_1' gs://mybucket/export
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041455/bigquery-backend-error-during-table-export) but I know that it is not a problem with my destination bucket in GCS, Because exporting other tables to same bucked is done successfully.

The only difference here is that this table has a repeated record field and each json can get pretty large but I did not find any limit for this on BigQuery docs.
Any ideas on what be the problem can be?

Job Id from one of my tries: `bqjob_r51435e780aefb826_0000015691dda235_1`

Comment: Did it used to work?

Comment: @polleyg No I have not tried exporting this very table before.

Comment: a job id would help to debug

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I added it to the question.